# Getting a FormPanel as well as GridPanel as a single JSON Store

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, extjs, jsonstore

How can I post a FormPanel as well as an EditorGrid ( Grid Panel) as a single JSON object in ExtJS with Rails 3.0.3?

For Ex: I have a FormPanel and a GridPanel, when it's submitted, it goes as a single JSON Store into the controller.

P.S: Any way to do that without using Arrays?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I want to send entire JSON containing Parent-Child Relation. Any Suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

you might want to split the submit event into two elements.
In other words, you can encapsulate the form and the grid on 2 separate elements you can check for all fields during the submit. That would create 2 separate post events.
However, why would you want to do that. you should just redirect the events of each individually as an action happens.
And no, extjs formats everything in a JSON that you would have to decode out to break the array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. well for now I am trying to submit just the form, but "Null" values are inserted. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: have you checked what is being posted via firebug? You can also use the inspect element on chrome and see the post on the network tab, under the xhr to your server side script.

Comment: The issue is solved now. I just used in Panel.js : ` var myform = Ext.getCmp('myform');
        myform.getForm().submit(
            url = '/customers/new',
            alert('Submitted'),
            window.open('customers.json')
            );
        })`                                                           and in Controller : format.json  { render :json => @customer, :success => true, :message => "Created new User #{@customer.id}",:customers => @customer }

Comment: cool. If my answer helped you out, please don't forget to vote on it as well.